# Dynamically added DataTemplate - StaticResource for Converter can't be found

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, datatemplate

I'm using the following code to dynamically add columns to my GridView:

```
public void AddGridViewColumns()
{
    GridView view = (GridView)_myListView.View;
    GridViewColumn column = BuildGridViewColumn(1);
    view.Columns.Add(column);
}

public virtual GridViewColumn BuildGridViewColumn(int blockIndex)
{
    string templateXaml = string.Format(
        @"<DataTemplate
            xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
            xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
            xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:Pse.MyTest;assembly=MyTest"">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <local:BlockToBrushConverter
                    x:Key=""_blockToBrushConverter"" />
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <TextBlock
                Style=""{{StaticResource _gridViewCenterItemStyle}}""
                Text=""{{Binding Path=Block{0}.ConditionLabel}}""
                Foreground=""{{Binding Path=Block{0}, Converter={{StaticResource _blockToBrushConverter}}}}"" />
        </DataTemplate>",
        blockIndex);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(templateXaml);
    GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
    column.Header = string.Format("Block {0}", blockIndex);
    column.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(templateXaml);
    return column;
}
```

The Debug.Print results in:

```
<DataTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pse.MyTest;assembly=MyTest">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <local:BlockToBrushConverter
            x:Key="_blockToBrushConverter" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock
        Style="{StaticResource _gridViewCenterItemStyle}"
        Text="{Binding Path=Block1.ConditionLabel}"
        Foreground="{Binding Path=Block1, Converter={StaticResource _blockToBrushConverter}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

When I run it, it says it cannot find _blockToBrushConverter.

The exception is:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message="Cannot find resource named '{_blockToBrushConverter}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file 'MyTest;component/SetupWindowDictionary.xaml' Line 23 Position 13."
  Source="PresentationFramework"
  LineNumber=23
  LinePosition=13
  NameContext="Foreground"
```

If I remove the Forecolor attribute, the XAML parses just fine (and I get the expected results). It seems like including the converter in DateTemplate.Resources should guarantee that it would be found, but for some reason it isn't.

I also tried moving the declaration for my converter resource higher in the tree (to the Window level), but that didn't work either. It seems to be able to find "_gridViewCenterItemStyle", but for some reason, it refuses to find the converter.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

---

Here's the entire exception with stack trace in case it helps:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message="Cannot find resource named '{_blockToBrushConverter}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file 'MyTest;component/SetupWindowDictionary.xaml' Line 23 Position 13."
  Source="PresentationFramework"
  LineNumber=23
  LinePosition=13
  NameContext="Foreground"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowException(String id, String parameter)
       at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IBamlReader bamlReader, Object targetObject, Object targetProperty, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
       at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ProvideValueFromMarkupExtension(MarkupExtension markupExtension, Object obj, Object member)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadOptimizedMarkupExtension(Object element, Int16 attributeId, PropertyDefinition propertyDefinition, Object value)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadPropertyWithStaticResourceIdRecord(BamlPropertyWithStaticResourceIdRecord bamlPropertyWithStaticResourceIdRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, ParserContext parserContext, OptimizedTemplateContent optimizedTemplateContent, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.GridViewRowPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at Pse.TestExperiment.App.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\Daniel Manes\My Documents\Projects\Cmd21\Team Map Experiment 2\Solution\TestExperiment\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

**EDIT:**

Problem solved: I did a search through my whole project and noticed I had an extra copy of the BlockToBrushConverter resource declaration with same x:Key in one of my resource dictionaries. Once I eliminated the duplication, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I've got a generated DataTemple very similar to your debug print - when I load it, I get "The attachable property Resources was not found in type DataTemplate" though my namespace includes and the rest of my xaml are identical except for the controls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case someone else takes a look at this question someday, it turns out, the code I presented at the top of this question actually works. The bug was that I had the following declaration elsewhere in my XAML:

```
<local:BlockToBrushConverter
    x:Key="_blockToBrushConverter" />
```

I believe this duplication prevented the resource from being declared locally for the dynamic DataTemplate (it couldn't create a resource with the same name twice within the same context).

One thing that is sort of unresolved for me is why some StaticResources need to be declared locally, while others (like the _gridViewCenterItemStyle StaticResource) can be declared higher in the tree (such as at the Window level) without a problem.